# Use generic parameterized with any type as function parameter

Tags: kotlin

I want the `mutate` function accepts both `BoxOf<Food>` and `BoxOf<Fruit>`.

```kotlin
interface Food

abstract class BoxOf<C : Food> {
    val children: MutableList<C> = mutableListOf()
}

interface Fruit : Food
class Apple : Fruit
class Lemon : Fruit

class BoxOfFood : BoxOf<Food>()
class BoxOfFruit : BoxOf<Fruit>()

fun mutate(parent: BoxOf<Food>) {
    parent.children.add(Apple())
    parent.children.remove(Lemon())
}

fun test() {
    mutate(BoxOfFood())
    mutate(BoxOfFruit()) // Type mismatch: inferred type is BoxOfFruit but BoxOf<Food> was expected
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to give `mutate` different kinds of `BoxOf<T>`, and put all kinds of fruits in it, it should take any "consumer" of `Fruit`, which is written `BoxOf<in Fruit>`:

```
fun mutate(parent: BoxOf<in Fruit>)
```

This allows you to pass any `BoxOf<T>` where `T` is a supertype of `Fruit` (and also a subtype of `Food`, due to the constraint of `BoxOf`).